# Report Parameters for RDLC and ReportViewer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer2008

I'm currently learning on how to do a filtering of reports of ReportViewer, I've done searching via internet and found some useful tips, here is what i did:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim USER As New ReportParameter("user", txtuser.Text)
    Try
        Me.DataTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet3.DataTable, DateTimePicker1.Value.Date, DateTimePicker2.Value.Date)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {USER})
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

and on the form load I added this code:

```
Private Sub AuditReport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Me.DataTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet3.DataTable,DateTimePicker1.Value.Date, DateTimePicker2.Value.Date)
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
end sub
```

The problem is when the ReportViewer loaded it does not show the data(contents) but the blanks like this:

[image]

and data only shows when I type on search user textbox like here:

[image]

Notice that when I type "label5" on textbox the data shows all label5, and that's my target, but what I also want is when the ReportViewer loaded, it should show all the data for reports not blanks, and if the textbox is blank it should show all data reports.

This is the paramater for search username:

[image]

Filtering report through date works just fine and it loads the data reports from the start but the problem happens when I tried to add report parameter for username filtering.

Comment: You did not set the parameter in your form load event

Comment: In default values: (at the end of the last image), uncheck "Null" and in expression use `=IIF(Parameters!Report_Parameter_0.Value ="",Nothing,Parameters!Report_Parameter_0.Value)`

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b that might be where the problem but I dont know how to set the parameter on form load,

Comment: @Jaxedin I tried your answer but it seems it does not recognize the "IIF" statement. it shows  sytax error

Comment: @Jaxedin my bad, its not syntax error, but a error on localprocessingexception

Comment: yeah, my bad also. Should have been `Parameters!user.Value` on both. `user` is your parameter name... or just pick it from the options when writing the formula.

Comment: Reportviewer shows "An error occurred during local report processing. Object reference not set to an instance of an object" , I dont have any idea on this :(

Comment: You need to assign a default value to your txtUser.Text or pass a value to your form and use that value as parameter to generate the report

Comment: Right ^. So add `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter("user", String.Empty))` between `Fill` and `RefreshReport()` lines on your Load event.

Comment: now the problem is InvalidCastException was unhandled, and it highlighted your statement, this for me is complicated, maybe you have alternative solution on filtering?

Comment: One quick question, if you replace you Load Event with `Button2.PerformClick()` does it work as needed?

Comment: tried to replace load event as suggested, but as the 1st image shows, it shows the table but no data, unless I type something on the textbox.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b as for my understanding on your suggestion, I tried to assign a default value on txtuser.text to generate report, but the problem is on load event, the data that is shown in only the default value of txtuser.text, not the whole data,

Comment: You are passing "" (blank) value to the report. SSRS will return all if you pass Nothing/Null as value. Have you tried sending Nothing as value? forget about the formula I wrote above.

Comment: still no luck sir, may this has something to do with me using vs 2008 express?